# SharePoint Online - Javascript get all list items into a select drop down

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

Hello I have a SharePoint content editor web part that has a drop down for a user to select an item. The select is only being filled with the first 100 items in the list I would like it to populate the 500+ items in the list.

Thank you

```
<script>
          $(document).ready(function () {  
              partnumDrpDownBind();  
            });  
          function partnumDrpDownBind() {  
              var listName = "Spec_ID_ABS_Primary";  
              var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;  

              getListItems(listName, url, function (data) {  
                  var items = data.d.results;  

                  var inputElement = '<select id="drpspecs"> <class="form-control"> <option  value="">Select</option>';  
                     // Add all the new items  
                  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {  
                       var itemId = items[i].Title,  
                         itemVal = items[i].Title;  
                       inputElement += '<option value="' + itemId + '"selected>' + itemId + '</option>';  

                     }  
                      inputElement += '</select>';  
                      $('#partnumdrp').append(inputElement);  

                    $("#drpspecs").each(function () {  
                      $('option', this).each(function () {  

                          if ($(this).text() == 'Select') {  
                              $(this).attr('selected', 'selected')  
                          };  
                      });  
                  });  
                     // assign the change event to provide an alert of the selected option value  
                   // $('#drpspecs').on('change', function () {  
                   // alert($(this).val());  
                    //    });  

                }, function (data) {  
                  alert("Ooops, an error occured. Please try again");  
              });  
          }  
          function getListItems(listName, siteurl, success, failure) {  
              $.ajax({  
                  url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$orderby=Title asc",  
                  method: "GET",  
                  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },  
                  success: function (data) {  
                      success(data);  
                  },  
                  error: function (data) {  
                      failure(data);  
                  }  
              });  
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint ODATA REST model limits the return items to 100 by default. You can override that limit by adding the $top query operator. This is to prevent the system from being bogged down.

```
// change the url: property of your ajax to this.
$.ajax({  
    url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$top=500&$orderby=Title asc",  
    method: "GET",  
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },  
    success: function (data) {  
        success(data);  
    },  
    error: function (data) {  
        failure(data);  
    }  
});
```

Be careful. If you return to many items it will slow things down.

MS Dev Center resource.
[Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests)

SharePoint Stack Exchange resource.
[ajax rest only returning 100 items instead of full list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169751/ajax-rest-only-returning-100-items-instead-of-full-list)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I gave the above a shot but i am still getting limited to the 100 results.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to put the & between the query operators. Try it now.

Comment: Yea still getting limited to the 100 results, stuff if coming in ordered by ascending even if i remove that query operator and try $top by itself

Comment: Not saying you haven't checked, but can you see if there are more than 100 items. Or try another list. I will give this more thought as well.

Comment: Yeah the list has over 500 items in it, tried with another list that has more than 100 items and I am still getting limited results. I appreciate your help